# Telnet to google mail server

Tags: smtp, telnet

I want to use telnet to google mail server on linux. I want to send mail using SMTP. But it is not able to do so. I am using this command.

```
telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

But it says

```
Trying 209.85.220.19...
```

After some time, it gives time out. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I don't know where that address comes from. I should think gmail.com would suffice. But I tried that, and got the same result. So, question is still open.

Comment: It connects for me. Perhaps that server was simply down at the time. The highest priority SMTP server is gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, though.

Comment: @BarryBrown, it isn't working :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It connects for me too. I think the most likely reason is that your ISP is blocking your external access to port 25. This is a common and sensible thing to do because SMTP from end-user PCs is a significant source of spam.

You may be able to talk your provider into opening the port up for you, or you can use a proxy server out on the 'net, or you can use a different service, such as SSMTP (?) which connects over a secure channel using a different port.

Answer (score 5):

Put `telnet smtp.gmail.com` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To run the telnet test on a Windows computer:

1. Open the Start menu, and select Run.
2. Enter command in the Open: field, and click OK.
3. Enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com **465**,' and hit Enter

Comment: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25` seems to work - however it asks for STARTTLS protocol to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You should also note that DNS records for mail servers have the "MX" type which is not the same as the standard "A" type that telnet uses.

In other words, "mail.google.com" can resolve to different IP addresses depending on whether you want to visit it as a webpage (or connect to via telnet), or send a mail to it.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, "mail.google.com" can resolve to different IP addresses depending on whether you want to visit it as a webpage (or connect to via telnet), or send a mail to it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).